# Problem running collvoid_local_planner

Tags: ros, navigation, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I tried to run the [collvoid](http://www.ros.org/wiki/multi_robot_collision_avoidance) package and ran into the same problem as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/44341/unable-to-get-collvoid-plugin-planner-for-navigation-stack-to-move-the-robot/). Only difference is that I still get the warning when I'm using navfn as global planner, so I guess the problem lies in the local planner (global plan is also displayed in rviz).
Does anybody know if there was an update since then to fix that problem? If not what else could be the problem here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70369/problem-running-collvoid_local_planner/) by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found out how to fix the warning "MSG to TF: Quaternion not properly normalized". But that does not influence the weird motion of my robot. It's still rotating in place. I guess there is somesthing wrong with the params in collvoid_params.yaml.
That is what I have done to fix the warning.

In the package collvoid_local_planner in file ROSAgent.cpp there is a function setAgentParams(). In that function the orientation will is calculated by tf::getYaw() which calls the method quaternionMsgToTF where the warning will be printed. So I normalized the quaternion myself in setAgentParams():

Before:

yaw = tf::getYaw(agent->base_odom_.pose.pose.orientation);

After:

tf::Quaternion quat(agent->base_odom_.pose.pose.orientation.x,
agent->base_odom_.pose.pose.orientation.y,
agent->base_odom_.pose.pose.orientation.z,
agent->base_odom_.pose.pose.orientation.w);

quat = quat.normalize();

yaw = tf::getYaw(quat);

---

Originally posted by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) with karma: 26 on 2013-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bbbExtremly](https://answers.ros.org/users/5281/bbbextremly/) on 2014-01-11**:
Would you mind sharing the source code of collvoid package? Because the original address is fail(rosws merge https://kforge.ros.org/collvoid/collvoid/raw-file/tip/collvoid.rosinstall) and I cannot download it. Thank you